# How to pass file names to MATLAB?

Tags: file, matlab, variables

In the directory that I am working, I have many files `file1 file2 file3` etc. I don't know the names of the files in advance, however I know that they are the only files starts with `A` , for example `A*.txt`.  How can I pass file names in an array to MATLAB?

Comment: Do you know the file names in advance? What do you want to do with the file names? Pass them to a function?

Comment: How about using a cell array of strings?

Comment: @Schorsch I have edited the post. You were right to  ask that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
files=dir('./A*.txt')
```

files is a structure, so you can acces the filenames with

```
files(Index).name
```

If you want all the filenames in an easy-to-use cellarray, try

```
cellarray = {files(:).name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad, so I'll make a few assumptions, namely that you don't mind cell arrays and that the files are of a specific extension. With that said, if you want to do it in a general manner and you know the extension, you can do:

EDIT: in light of the fact that you know the first part of the filename, you can modify your call to the `dir` function reflect that:

```
%have the part of the filename you know here, in your question that being 'A'
file_prefix = 'A';
file_path = pwd;
%this will get all of the .txt files. Put the extension you want here
file_names = dir(strcat(file_path,filesep,file_prefix,'*.txt'));  
fnames = cell(length(file_names), 1);
for i=1:length(file_names)
    fnames{i} = file_names(i).name; 
end
```

This will give a cell array of strings containing all of the filenames of the specified extension, which you can pass to whatever needs the filenames. You can generalize this to get the file names from any directory by specifying the path (instead of using `pwd`, which gets the contents of the current directory)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short and simple answer:

`filenames = dir('A*')`

This assumes you want to return files in the present directory beginning with "A", you could build off this example as needed though.